# Is it appropriate to post questions about Minecraft servers on the main site?

Tags: discussion, allowed-questions

I wanted to post a question regarding hosting a Minecraft server 'Does disabling the nether improve server performance?'.

It feels a bit out of place on the main site, however I wouldn't really know -where- to ask such a question if it isn't appropriate there.

*Edit: Other questions could be asking about server settings, plugins etc. I ask this because it is less about the game play and more about the server admininstration.*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Questions about Minecraft servers are on-topic here, but your specific question:

> Does disabling the nether improve server performance?

would not do well—and would possibly even be closed as "Not a Real Question" or "Not Constructive"—without expansion and clarification of what, exactly, you mean by "server performance". Framerate? Latency? The ability to have more concurrent users? Memory usage?

If you can enumerate the exact metrics you're looking to improve, your question would be appropriate here.

Comment: Awesome stuff, thanks Mark.

Answer (score 1):

This feels on topic to me - it is a specific requirement when playing a game that performance is sufficient.

But first, have a read of [this Q&A](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/73712/6028) to see if any info in there improves your performance.